# Query with GROUP_CONCAT not working

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions, group-concat

I have 3 tables with the following structure:

```
**users**
id 
first_name
last_name


**specialties**
specialty_id
specialty_name


**user_specialties**
user_id
specialty_id
```

Here is some sample data:

```
**users**
1  Bill  Smith
2  Tom   Jones
3  Jill  Hayes


**specialties**
1  word
2  web
3  database

**user_specialties**
1  1
2  1
2  3
3  2
3  3
```

I need to query the data so the specialties are concatinated on one row like the below output

```
**Desired Result**
Bill  Smith  word
Tom   Jones  word,database
Jill  Hayes  web,database
```

I am using the following query

```
SELECT
users.first_name,
users.last_name,
GROUP_CONCAT(specialties.specialtyname)
FROM
users 
LEFT JOIN user_specialties ON user_specialties.user_id = users.userid
RIGHT JOIN specialties ON user_specialties.specialty_id = specialties.specialty_id
```

It is not working...

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a `GROUP BY` clause. Most likely it should be `GROUP BY users.id`, and it'd go AFTER the JOIN lines.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested this query

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,group_concat(specialty_name) 
FROM user_specialties map 
INNER JOIN specialties skill on user.id = map.user_id 
INNER JOIN users user ON skill.specialty_id = map.specialty_id 
GROUP BY user.id
```

Cheers! :-)

Comment: +1 for a working example, but -1 for non-ANSI join syntax. So, +0 :)

Comment: @Dan select first_name,last_name,group_concat(specialty_name) 
from user_specialties map INNER JOIN specialties skill
on user.id = map.user_id
INNER JOIN users user
ON skill.specialty_id = map.specialty_id
group by user.id